# How to update an XML file while the Android app is running in a device or emulator?

Tags: android, xml

Can anyone tell me a way to store an XML file in the android apps so that I can update it in a regular basis just like we do it in SQlite database.
I am developing an apps in which I use an xml file to store data and I need to update the data on regular basis, please tell me a way to store the xml file.
Means where should I store that xml file so that I can update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Means where shud I store that xml file so that I can update it.

Usually, you will want to save it in the private directory for your app. You can get a pointer to that directory by invoking the [`getFilesDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) method from an Activity or other kind of contexts. Other useful method is [`openFileOutput`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) which returns a `FileOutputStream` that you can use to save a file. This should answer your question how "where to save" the file.

Comment: Thanks Cristian, I got your point and currently I am doing this also where I put my XML file into the private directory of the app ie; data/data/[package]/File_Name. I just copied the file from the server and put it inside this files directory of the app.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation on Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is good, this should give you an idea of which method best suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I got the idea of achieving this target this documents is really helpful for me to do so.

Comment: Here is another link which is very much helpful, have a look at it: [Click here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidFileSystem/article.html)